Interference for 2 oblique EM wave
I found this equation for the irradiance of 2 EM waves interfering in oblique in the book "Fundamental of Photonics":


So, the average Irradiance along x is 2*I0.

But if the angle (theta) = zero, then the average irradiance according to above equation is 4*I0.
My question: why there is discrepancy between the above 2 results?

If they are parallel, $\theta = 0,$ and one wave is $u_1=Ae^{\mathfrak j\alpha_1}e^{-\mathfrak j kz}$ and the other is $u_2=Ae^{\mathfrak j\alpha_2} e^{-\mathfrak j kz}$, then their sum is $u_0=u_1+u_2=Be^{-\mathfrak j kz}$ where $B=A(e^{\mathfrak j\alpha_1}+e^{\mathfrak j\alpha_2}).$ Depending on the relative phase $\alpha_2-\alpha_1$ of the interfering waves, the intensity $|B|^2$ of the sum $u_0$ varies between $0$ and $4|A|^2.$

But how the intensity |B|2 varies based on the phase shift? doesn't that violate the conservation of energy. Note: the 2 waves are in parallel; hence, there is no fringes.

It does not violate energy conservation because it does not propagate "out", instead it gets reflected back to the source. Think of a power  amplifier connected to a mismatched transmission line.

thanks. You said that "the intensity |B|2 of the sum u0 varies between 0 and 4|A|2". Can you give an example for 2 parallel waves with interfering intensity 4|A|2?

Illuminate a 3dB splitter simultaneously from two sides, the sources should be phase locked with each other or just a single source split in two ways. In one arm between the splitter and the source you place a phase shifter and an attenuator to adjust the relative phase in the common output:$A+A=2A$.
